# Tips for golfing in Clojure

Tags: code-golf, tips, lisp

What are your tips for code golfing using Clojure?

The aim of this question is to collect a list of techniques that are specific to Clojure and can be used in general code-golfing problems.

Comment: Hmm.. shouldn't these types of posts be in meta (granted I'm not sure meta existed 5+ years ago)

Answer (score 6):

Use reader syntax for lambdas.
So use

```
#(+ % %2 %3)
```

instead of

```
(fn [x y z] (+ x y z))
```

You can also eliminate whitespace some of the time:

```
#(if (< % 0) (- %) %)
#(if(< % 0)(- %)%)
```

Comment: by the way `#(+ % %2 %3)` is equivalent to `+`.

Answer (score 5):

## Where you can remove whitespace:

- Between a string and anything else:

  ```
  (println(+"Hello, World!"1))
  ```
- Between brackets and anything else:

  ```
  (for[x(range 5)](* x x))
  ```
- Between a number and everything other than builtins or variable names:

  ```
  Allowed:
  (+ 1"Example")
  (map{1"-1"2"-2"}[1 2 3])

  Not allowed:
  (+1 2)
  ```
- Between `@` (dereference for atoms) and brackets.

Comment: Also before the deref reader macro `@`

Comment: Also at times you might be able to re-arrange stuff at a `let` and get rid of some spaces.

Comment: Also before parameters in anonymous functions: `#(+ 1(first%))` = `#(+ 1 (first %))`

Answer (score 3):

**Strings can be treated as a sequence of chars**

e.g. to sort the characters in a string alphabetically:

```
(sort "hello")
=> (\e \h \l \l \o)
```

Comment: Strings are by definition a sequence of chars in almost every language, but you can't apply this trick in all of them :-)

Comment: Or rather, "sequence" has a special meaning in Clojure than means you can apply extra tricks ::-)

Answer (score 2):

## Use `nth ... 0` instead of `first`

To get the first element of a collection, using `(nth ... 0)` over `first` saves a byte:

```
(first[2 3 4]): 14 bytes
(nth[2 3 4]0): 13 bytes (saves a byte!)
```

Comment: same goes for `second` (2 bytes)

Comment: Also you can use vectors as functions, so `([2 3 4]1)` returns the element at index 1. This should be benefitical if for example the input format is flexible.

Answer (score 2):

## Use maps instead of `if`s when testing for equality

```
;; if n=3 then A else B
(if (= 3 n) A B) ; (if(=3n)AB)
({3 A} n B)      ; ({3A}nB) -> -3 chars

;; if n=2 or n=3 then A else B
(if (#{2 3} n) A B) ; (if(#{23}n)AB)
({2 A 3 A} n B)     ; ({2A3A}nB) -> -4 chars
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use apply instead of reduce

For example `#(apply + %)` is one byte shorter than `#(reduce + %)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Bind long function names at let to a single-byte symbol

For example if you need to use `partition` or `frequencies` multiple times, it could be beneficial to bind them to a single-byte symbol in a `let` macro. Then again it might not be worth it if you don't need the `let` otherwise, and the function name is relatively short.

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid let if you already have a for

For example: `#(for[a[(sort %)]...)` instead of `#(let[a(sort %)](for ...))`.

For does also have a `:let` construct but it is too verbose for code golf.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `+` and `-` instead of `inc` and `dec`

This saves 1 byte if you're using `inc`/`dec` on an expression with parens:

```
(inc(first[1 3 5]))
(+(first[1 3 5])1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use for instead of map

For instance `#(for[i %](Math/abs i))` is a lot shorter than the `map` equvalent.