# Shortest code to check if a string has only letters

Tags: code-golf, string

Your task is to create a program which takes a string, and if it contains **any** numbers, symbols or other non-letter characters, it throws an error. Else, it returns the original string. (The string may include whitespace)

("Letters" are a-z and A-Z)

Examples:

**Input:** `My name is Joe`

**Output** `My name is Joe`

---

**Input:** `My username is Joe32`

**Output:** `(insert an error)`

(FYI this question has nothing to do with Don't Google google. It was identified as a possible copy.)

Comment: Can we read the string from `stdin`?

Comment: Specify the exact ASCII range that is allowed.

Comment: @sweerpotato Yes, you can

Comment: @minxomat a-z, A-Z, and whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't google "google"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58891/dont-google-google)

Comment: @mbomb007 In what way is this a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: When you way "whitespace," do you mean _any_ whitespace character, including tabs and newlines, or only spaces?

Comment: @Alex A. Yes, I mean any whitespace character

Comment: In fact, there are even more [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) in the ASCII range namely vertical tabs, carriage returns and form feeds.

Comment: Retina would be a _great_ programming language for this task...

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Except, I can't think of a way to make it throw an error based on the input. :/

Comment: @AlexA. It's a simple "check the input, if fits certain condition, then throw error, else do something else simple" question.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yeah, I was trying to think of a way for the Google one, but idk enough about the structure of Retina for that. Could you get a runtime error by having an invalid configuration string, or is there no way to make that step be skipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
êF┼Aµ╧û┤
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8846c541e6cf96b4&i=My+name+is+Joe%0AMy+username+is+Joe32&a=1&m=2)

Shortest solution so far but expect to be defeated soon.

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
' Vl+-!uy
' Vl+        Alphabet plus space
     -       Remove from input
      !u     If result is not empty raise division by zero error
        y    Else print input
```

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, 53 bytes

```julia
s=readline();ismatch(r"[^a-z\s]"i,s)?error():print(s)
```

Read a string from STDIN using `readline()`. If any of its characters are not letters or whitespace (`ismatch(r"[^a-z\s]"i, s)`) then we `error()`, otherwise we `print(s)`.

Answer (score 3):

## Gema, 14 characters

```
\W<-L>=@div{;}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\W<-L>=@div{;}' <<< 'My name is Joe'
My name is Joe

bash-4.3$ gema '\W<-L>=@div{;}' <<< 'My username is Joe32'
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++14, <strike>132</strike> <strike>126</strike> <strike>121</strike> <strike>117</strike> 121 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
main(){std::string s;getline(std::cin,s);for(char c:s)if(!isalpha(c)&!isspace(c))throw;std::cout<<s;}
```

We read a line from `stdin`, check if each character is a letter or space - if it's not, we throw an error. Finally outputs the input.

*Thanks to Alex A for golfing off two bytes*

Comment: Isn't `std::getline` defined in `<string>` header? Also, I think it is C++11 (I am not saying it is not C++14 though)

Comment: `std::getline` isn't defined in `<string>`. Yes, it probably is - but I'm compiling it in C++14 so I find it safer to write it that way. Thanks anyway :~)! Actually, regular `getline` is defined in `iostream` which saves me 5 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

#### PowerShell, 24 bytes

Filter the pipeline input based on whether it matches the regex:

```powershell
|?{$_-match'^[a-z\s]+$'}
```

e.g. try it by piping the string in:

```powershell
PS C:\> "Test Test"|?{$_-match'^[a-z\s]+$'}
Test Test

PS C:\> "Test ! Test"|?{$_-match'^[a-z\s]+$'}
```

The error message is silence/empty result.
It matches case-insensitively by default.

Comment: Empty result isn't really an error, though? I came up with `param($a)if($a-replace'[a-z\s]',''){1/0;exit}$a` for 47 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### STATA, 57 bytes

```
di _r(a)
gl b=1/regexm("$a","^[a-zA-Z ]*$")
di _d($b)"$a"
```

Uses a regex to match letters and space (STATA's regex doesn't include character classes). Set a variable to 1/match exists. Then it prints a that many times, if match exists=0, it says it's invalid syntax. Otherwise, it prints it 1/1 = 1 time.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
q_"  
"'[,_el^|-!/
```

The multi-line string contains a tabulator, a space and a linefeed.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_%22%09%20%0A%22'%5B%2C_el%5E%7C-!%2F&input=My%20username%20is%20Joe32).

#### How it works

```
q_                    Read all input from STDIN and push a copy.
  "\t \n"             Push that string.
         '[,_el^      Push all letters. See: codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54348
                |     Concatenate both strings.
                 -    Remove their characters from the copy of the input.
                  !   Logical NOT. Pushes 0 if there are other characters.
                   /  Split. Doesn't affect output if successful. Errors on 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 56 characters

```
import re;print(re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',input(),2).string)
```

Usefully, match objects have this attribute [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.string) which is

> The string passed to match() or search().

while `None` does not.

```
In [10]: import re;print(re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',input(),2).string)
54
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0851dec671d1> in <module>()
----> 1 import re;print(re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',input(),2).string)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

In [11]: import re;print(re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',input(),2).string)
rffef 
rffef
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> <s>46</s> *31* Bytes

```
/[^a-z\s]/i.exec(a=prompt())?q:a
```

Accepts input, searches for invalid characters, if it finds any, returns a truthy value and thus evaluates the undefined character `q`. Otherwise, returns null and thus returns the string.

### Old version, 44 bytes

```
~(a=prompt()).search(/[^a-z\s]/i)?eval("@"):a
```

Tries to evaluate the invalid character `@` upon finding a numeric.

---

<s>Edit 1: -2 bytes, thanks to @Alex A.</s>

Edit 2: -1 byte, reworked. BONUS: Accounts for ALL whitespace! ^_^

Edit 3: +1 byte, added underscore testing.

Edit 4: Back to 46, unreworked.

Edit 5: -2 extra bytes to @edc65 (for old version; -1 for new).

Comment: Can you use a regex option to make it case insensitive? I don't know the JS regex flavor but you may be able to do `/[^a-z ]/gi` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Per the OP's comment, looks like we need to account for all whitespace characters, not just spaces. For that you may be able use `/[^a-z\s]/gi`.

Comment: From the OP's second example, it looks like we are supposed to throw the error if numbers are in the string.

Comment: @AlexA. Yeah; by DeMorgan's laws, the negation of a disjunction (the regular expression) results in a conjuction of the negatives of the expression. Input the expression into RegExr.com to get a visual of the matched expressions.

Comment: @edc65 I don't know why your comment was upvoted. You are wrong in your statement.

Comment: We cannot know everything. I for instance don't know why you posted an aswer without trying the test in the question. Now that you fixed it, you can still save 2 bytes using `~(a=prompt()).search(/[^a-z\s]/i)?eval("@"):a`

Comment: @edc65 It worked in the beginning; golfing complicated it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 166 Bytes

```
func main(){r="";foreach(c in input()){c=c.toString();if(!("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \t\n\r".contains(c)))throw(c);else r+=c;}println(r);}
```

Run and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=339a688e71a7624371c83b1cbf61ec56)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 56 bytes

```
q x|all(`elem`(['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']++['\t'..'\r']))x=x
```

Throws the `Non-exhaustive patterns in function q` error if the string contains forbidden characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 60 bytes

```
import re;n=input();print[n][re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\s]+','',n)!=n]
```

Usage:

```
$ python -c "import re;n=input();print[n][re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\s]+','',n)!=n]"
"abcdefg"
abcdefg
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```
<?=preg_match('/[^a-z\s]/i',$a=$argv[1])?e():$a;
```

Runs from command line, like:

```
php test.php "Test me"
```

---

Using `preg_match` is shorter than using `ctype_alpha` as the latter needs whitespaces to be stripped.

---

As the error wasn't defined in the challenge, calling an undefined function seems the shortest way to generate an error. So this:

```
php test.php "Test me, 2"
```

leads to:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function e()

### Edit

Saved **3 bytes** by inverting the statement an by using the [`i`-modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Thanks to [fschmengler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43220/fschmengler).

Comment: You can save a few bytes with the case insensitive modifier `i` instead of `a-zA-Z`. And even more if you negate the expression: `<?=preg_match('/[^a-z\s]/i',$a=$argv[1])?e():$a;` (it searches for any character that is not a white space or alphabetic character) I replaced `` with `\s` because the question said, all whitespaces are allowed.

Comment: @fschmengler Thanks a lot - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>68</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```
import re;s=raw_input();print s if re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',s,2)else 0/0
```

Thanks to [Alex A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469/alex-a) and [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) for saving a byte and [NightShadeQueen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45325/nightshadequeen) for another byte!

Comment: You should be able to shorten your regex by removing the position anchors and the `+`. You could also take out one of `A-Z` or `a-z` if there's an easy way to make it a case-insensitive regex.

Comment: @AlexA. The `+` has to stay, because the regex ensures that the string consists *only* of those characters. But I think the anchors *might* be unnecessary, because IIRC `match` checks against the entire string anyway (`scan` looking for substrings instead).

Comment: Thanks both. I was able to remove the beginning anchor as yes, `match` automatically searches from the start of the string.

Comment: @AlexA. It looks like I can make the regex case-insensitive with `re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',s,re.I)` but it's more bytes than the case-sensitive expression. Thanks though!

Comment: `re.I` is just 2. You could do `re.match(r'[a-z\s]+$',s,2)`

Comment: Ah, hadn't though of that; thanks @NightShadeQueen!

Answer (score 0):

## Java 127 Bytes

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){String s=System.console().readLine();System.out.print(s.matches("[A-z ]+")?s:0/0);}}
```

In Java from the command line you can have input and with the help of regular expression `[A-z ]+` which matches alphabets and space in the line, you can have this kind of trick.Moreover, `0/0` will throw `ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <del>26</del> 25 bytes

"undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)":

```
+(gets=~/^[A-z]*$/);print
```

Previous 26 bytes, "in `/': divided by 0 (ZeroDivisionError)":

```
puts gets[/^[A-z]*$/]||1/0
```

Answer (score 0):

### **C#** - **<strike>174</strike> <strike>157</strike> 148 bytes**

```
using System.Linq;namespace System{class A{static void Main(string[]s){if(!s[0].All(char.IsLetter))throw new Exception();Console.WriteLine(s[0]);}}}
```

usage:

Console application that takes a parameter in the form of a string and checks via LINQ if all the characters in that string are letters. If so, writes it to console. Otherwise throws exception.

Not particularly short. Will keep tinkering!

Edit: Think I'm pretty much done. Can't get it much shorter don't think.