# Divisible strings

Tags: code-golf, string

## Task

Given a string `s`, output a truthy value if the ASCII code of each letter is divisible by the length of `s`, and a falsey otherwise.

### Input/Output

Input is a nonempty string containing only ASCII `[32-126]`. Output is a standard truthy/falsey value. Note that you can switch the values, for example returning `0`/`False` if divisible and vice versa

### Test cases

```
Input         Output

Hello         False       (72 101 108 108 111), 5
lol           True        (108 111 108), 3
Codegolf      False       (67 111 100 101 103 111 108 102), 8
A             True        (65), 1
nope          False       (110 111 112 101),4
8  8          True        (56 32 32 56), 4
```

Comment: Suggested truthies `off` and `fir`

Comment: @J42161217 I would rather add more test cases if they are either long truthy cases or very short falsey cases. We already have a 3-letter truthy.

Comment: "UPZAP" (not sure if that's a real word, but could refer to changing TV channel to a higher-numbered one using a remote control...)

Comment: @Dion I just thought it would be nice to include a real word...good luck in finding bigger ones

Comment: Can we switch truthy/falsey return values (ie return a falsey value if the ASCII code of each letter is divisible by the length of s, and a truthy otherwise.)

Comment: @Noodle9 sure, I guess that's acceptable

Comment: Please let all existing solutions know that output may be reversed as, like me, they may be able to save some bytes.

Comment: @Shaggy I edited the post in order to clarify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
tn\~
```

- For divisible strings the output is a vector containing only `1`s, which is [truthy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398).
- Otherwise the output is a vector containing several `1`s and at least one `0`, which is [falsy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQvpu7/f/Wc/Bx1AA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwDIbve4pcpA5k5@FFRA8@gEcFx5atgdiUNUV20FevlSFMMJDwJ3z8@e@NcrrBt1bQSVVVD0uMsCbXkyNFYBFfJnWXV9oZHaPayWSWepiXLfgYLKilAEFHckPxNH3DIWOZQw74B7ku3qLriuMyBgXPzVScF7fZYIy4ARXwo3SxRWgc/OTMse@eqSX9mJbJnJBZTGFYOM@DdDgI91nuc9cAtXkD) including truthiness/falsihood test.

#### How it works

```
t   % Implicit input. Duplicate
n   % Number of elements
\   % Modulo
~   % Negate. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 31 bytes

Output is via exit code, `1` for truthy, `0` for falsey cases.

```
#v~\1+
v>53p
>:#v_1q
^  >' %#@_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X7msLsZQm6vMztS4gMvOSrks3rCQK05BwU5dQVXZIf7//5z8HAA)

---

Code running with inputs `lol` and `ab`:

[image: Code with input lol]
[image: Code with input ab]

<sup>small numbers represent literal byte values</sup>

Comment: Wow!  The animation is amazing!  Can we have this for every Befunge answer, please?

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ÇsgÖP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHtx@uFpAf//5@TnAAA)

**Commented**

```python
        # implicit input    "lol"
Ç       # push ASCII value  [108, 111, 108]
 s      # swap (with input) [108, 111, 108], "lol"
  g     # length            [108, 111, 108], 3
   Ö    # is divisible?     [1, 1, 1]
    P   # product           1
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```hs
(<1).sum.(map=<<flip(mod.fromEnum).length)
```

```hs
f s=sum[fromEnum c`mod`length s|c<-s]<1
```

3 fewer bytes thanks to ovs and xnor!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADArzTE1cEdRl9hTCAIQmyLobD593pXgjwJUTWDOJl05N5o50kQPbXLY@J7FJAv2lVOuymFyuDg7ZUHLJDBYEOjPw)

Comment: Welcome! Here's a trick to get the code working on TIO: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcwxDoAgDADArzTGAQZJ3GE08REuRC0SW2hEv2/1HnBHbOdOpBgWNX60rj3sDEcJ3iNlMVw3h1flqTxsHe0l3YdVjrlAALlyuaEHhG7@l9rpuyLF1HRYRT4 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: pointfree is a little bit longer in this case: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2La4NDc6Nz9FI60oP9c1rzRXIVlTJSc1L70kQ6G4JtlGtzjWxvB/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoJSTn6O0n8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @ovs You can even infix the `mod` to cut parens: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADArzTE1cEdRl9hTCAIQmyLobD593pXgjwJUTWDOJl05N5o50kQPbXLY@J7FJAv2lVOuymFyuDg7ZUHLJDBYEOjPw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Another 39 with some partial pointfreeing: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs7DoAgEAXAq2yMBRSS2Gtp4jEgKGB8fAJ4fVenn2DafQLMjrAaQIhllkromA@NM/keCFK5muOWnijB0VyJVir1Sp1GcjTs/88Dv9bB@MaTLeUD "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

Ouput is reversed.

```
s=>Buffer(s).some(c=>c%s.length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc0xDoMwEAXRPqdASEh2Edc0RiJpcg1kdg1o449YJ9c31Mjtm2K26T9pONY9PxNmKuyL@uH1Y6bDqHWKL5ngh9CpE0oxL7YEJIWQE0TDpv2QCFprHzcXSEXf1yVCuJLGiiXsVOG@afqLywk)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [@isaag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg)

```
!%#lQCM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1FVOSfQ2ff/f/Wc/Bz1f/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

```
!%#lQCM
!        - logical negation of
  #      - filtering
     CM  - ascii values of input with
 % lQ    - func(x): return x % len(input)
```

Comment: Alternate solution for 8 bytes: `!s%RlQCM`

Comment: Yet another: `!f%CTlQQ`  
Filter string with `ascii(letter) % length`

Comment: Combining Sok and Scott's solutions gives a 7 byte solution: `!%#lQCM`

Answer (score 5):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>205</s> <s>192</s> <s>175</s> 162 bytes

Well, this was fun. Rockstar has no way of reading the length of a string directly, can't convert characters to codepoints and has no modulo operator. Surprised it worked out this short!

```
listen to S
cut S
X's0
D's0
while S at X
N's32
while N-127
cast N into C
if C is S at X
let M be N/S
turn down M
let D be+N-S*M

let N be+1

let X be+1

say not D
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>56</s> 52 bytes

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i++]);$c%strlen($argn)?die(f):1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVkm3zi1I0VBKL0vOiVTK1tWM1gWKqxSVFOal5EGFN@5TMVI00TStDTev//z1Sc3Ly/@UXlGTm5xX/13UDAA)

Output is reversed

Execution stops with `f` if any char is not divisible, or empty string (falsy in PHP) if all are divisible

EDIT: saved 4 bytes thanks to @640KB

Comment: Nice one. Alternate take [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVkm3zi1I0VBKL0vOiVTK1tWM1gWKqxSVFOal5EGFN@5TMVA1DPU0rQ03r//89UnNy8v/lF5Rk5ucV/9d1AwA) or [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVkm3zi1I0VBKL0vOiVTK1tWM1gWKqxSVFOal5EGFN@5TMVI00TStDTev//z1Sc3Ly/@UXlGTm5xX/13UDAA) if you are willing to output `f` for `Falsey` and empty for `Truthy`.

Comment: Or a bit of a [wierdo one](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsIwEADv@4pQIjSo9CpEERGlB0HvKqLtxgZCNmwiXny7USviYWBgYEIX8nQeugDYdCTkma9@JIpDKnQ2xKWWzYy4Lfuwl3Y4PCot@TGTzSAmdui/SSn9GUjWuR/t6t1ptd1oqCrBGDGJC6Y7ohcJYxJ88xHeYCqlVfqn7q@sdK7ROQJHDpbU4pWcgQV4CggTISZAxoCx/KSQLPmYx@sX) if you can return `0` for `Falsey` and non-zero for `Truthy`

Comment: @640KB great suggestion, never thought that `ord(NULL)` would be `0`, should have tried.. and should have thought of moving the exit inside the `for`, it's usually something that I test :) I like the weird one too

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```python
lambda s:all(ord(i)%len(s)<1for i in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr3QxtKOORie/4YKBapNKCbD4@npXv/FYWZz30zW@V4rQ16iK1hIKTZoLdtpmtgYCUqCT1yZlIGM4LOXblAOR/w)

-2 bytes thanks to @ovs

Comment: 39 bytes with `all`: `lambda s:all(ord(i)%len(s)<1for i in s)`.

Comment: Don't delete your answer since the cat is already out of the bag but usually you don't answer your own question for a few days to give other people a shot at it - as OP you have an unfair time advantage.

Comment: If you accept "truthy" to be False and "falsey" to be True, then you can spare two bytes by removing `<1` and substituting `any` for `all`.

Comment: @Stef I was thinking about that. I would rather go with standard truthy-falsey values, and im not sure how well that goes

Comment: Also a valid Python 3 solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
{0}==##&@@ToCharacterCode@#~Mod~Tr[1^#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277v9qg1tZWWVnNwSEk3zkjsSgxuSS1yDk/JdVBuc43P6UupCjaME45Vu1/QFFmXomCvkO6gxZcXbG@Q7WSR2pOTr6SjlJOfg6QBGlNz89JAzIdgdhCQcECLFemVPv/PwA)

thanks to @att for saving some bytes

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6TIwTc/JTok3zkjsSgxuSS1yDk/JdVBWccnNS@9JMNBOdbGUO1/QFFmXomCvkO6gxZcXbG@Q7WSR2pOTr6SjlJOfg6QBGlNz89JAzIdgdhCQcFCqfb/fwA) taking a list of characters instead of a string

Comment: @att your code checks only the first character. That is why it fails for `lov` because `Tr@{{0}, {0}, {1}}=0` . I made some changes and now it works

Comment: Ah, right, forgot that `ToCharacterCode` returns a list for single characters as well. Looks like your modification is `Total`ing the character codes before taking the `Mod`, though. [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277v9qg1tZWWVnNwSEk3zkjsSgxuSS1yDk/JdVBuc43P6UupCjaME45Vu1/QFFmXomCvkO6gxZcXbG@Q7WSR2pOTr6SjlJOfg6QBGlNz89JAzIdgdhCQcECLFemVPv/PwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 11 bytes

```
{~+/(#x)!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82quk5bX0O5QlOxovZ/mrqGkkdqTk6@krWCUk5@Dohyzk9JTc/PSQOxHUFEXn5BKoi2UFCwUNL8DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```c
l;r;f(char*s){l=strlen(s);for(r=0;*s;)r|=*s++%l;l=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BSsQwEIbv@xRjoJC0XayKsBIryCL4DraHpU3WQkxKJodi7bPXJK3dPRhIZjLzzz98zf7cNPOsuOWSNp8nmyIbVYnOKqEpMi6NpbYseIqc2Z8yxSxLFFel5dPcaQdfp05Ttht34E80ACfQ4UcNJYzkXShlSA5EGRXC0bTibJQM@Wt4tOlFiAeAA5l4tAm@YujF4EQbfWAscrjL4fKuymWhXZdVw9t9NTwd/X0Mnlf/h@AdRzwQ0LCh060Y/FzB1/QZsPsWRtK/3ex2LaRbhUOWRTWDBfkK23st6FFQ860feXx3Y/pPgF5wI6ljl3JvfUNSUpEEKwL7F0ha8Kn2cC4HzD259y0B63Vq2k3zLw)

Returns falsey if the ASCII value of each character is divisible by the length of the input string or truthy otherwise.

#### Explanation:

```c
l;r;f(char*s){l=strlen(s);for(r=0;*s;)r|=*s++%l;l=r;}  
l;r;                                                  // Declare 2 int variables
    f(                                                // Function f taking
      char*s){                                        //   string parameter s  
              l=strlen(s);                            // Store length of s in l
                          for(                        // Loop
                              r=0;                    //   initialising r to 0
                                  *s;)                //   until end of s  
                                      r|=             // Bitwise or r with 
                                         *s           //   the ASCII value of the next
                                                      //   character...  
                                           ++         // Aside: push s pointer forward
                                             %l;      //  ... mod the string length
                                                l=r;  // Return r (r will be 0
                                                      //   iff every character was
                                                      //   divisible by the length of the   
                                                      //   input string)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```rust
|s|s.iter().all(|x|1>x%s.len()as u8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jczBCoJAEMbxu0@xCsUslNBNKoQIpHeIiBVnRZjccnZBaH12W4OgS@Ech//36xzbUbfippoWpHhGIpxFtjB69pw2FjuQqSIC3/tN3i84JQypYuEyOU653EVDFIxpti@2omhheXbZRa7z0hjKQYffx1bM2NkrPmKoyjoGDWVyQiKTSLkSWhFj8H6VZOjd2c79y46mwtqQnmUe5oitueMsLRMi@waH8QU)

Takes the input as a `&[u8]`, outputs a `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>43</s> <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.bytes.all?{|n|n%a.size<1}}
```

if only map could be used on strings..

-10 bytes from ovs.

-1 byte from Dingus.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLi8IwEL7PrxgKgkItndbWHqwiwrJ72svexEOKqQRCUvo4@Prt3Ym2uxcd8iWT4ZtvHnVXnPu8kCdl4MtUXYujfXctfwE@pdb2L/ohdCMHf7qMkEJiZE8QzXxMQFuN//ZTd2MCTgeaozM1hp09ypPV5QvxdDkww6FIPGYyIs7OYIv4rlCaMIPA2Eri6@aJwqcgPaaY@QvIELM3ekmKceROkrLwAnJpjgBl3s/X4iqC4tzKJhBab643czMTETTqIld0v/elrVGhMrj3Hqv0fI8XxPc4O7tbhmuVH9eDdwCssNyrA7gy/S8)

Comment: You don't need the brackets around `&:zero?`: https://tio.run/##dVBNa8MwDL3rV4jARgtpiJMmDYW0lMHYTrvsVnpwqFIMnh3ycejXb8/kNtkurfCzZfPek6y6K459XtBBGfg0VdfiGF9dy1eAD9La/r2@S93QkE8WEYpQMLI7hJj6mIC2Gv/ju@5GAU4GmqMzNYY3u6eD1eUD83QxMMOhSDwqGRGrM9ggPiuUJswQYGxF@Lh5IcK7obj9YurPIUPMnvglKcaRW0nKxnPIyewByryfreRZBsWxpSb4kdX5Yi7mRQaNOtE1kFqv8XV5otqur31pa1SoDG6921A93@NR8T5OgdMNwzXNh@vG2wFWWG7VDlzB/hc

Comment: Yep, missed that. Havent golfed ruby in around a month lol

Comment: And putting the `==0` in the map shortens this a little more: `->a{a.bytes.all?{|n|n%a.size==0}}`

Comment: yes, that shortens it a lot.

Comment: You can save one more byte with `<1` instead of `==0`.

Comment: Is `0` not falsey in Ruby? Tried `->a{!a.bytes.any?{|n|n%a.size}}` for 31 but it didn't work.

Comment: 0 is truthy in ruby, yes. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Shaggy: Only `false` and `nil` are falsey in Ruby. `0`, empty array, empty hash, empty strings are all truthy, for example.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 20 bytes

```perl
$_=!grep ord()%@F,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYxvSi1QCG/KEVDU9XBTcfB7f9/j9ScnHyunPwcLuf8lNT0/Jw0LkeuvPyCVC6Lf/kFJZn5ecX/dXMK3AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
₌CLœΠ
```

Thanks @Lyxal for saving 3 bytes
[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%8CCL%C5%93%CE%A0&inputs=%5B%22A%22%5D%20&header=&footer=)

Comment: [5 bytes by porting Jelly](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%8CCL%C5%93%CE%A0&inputs=%5B%22A%22%5D%20&header=&footer=)

Comment: [here's what it looks like with the new codepage](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%8CCL%E1%B8%8A%CE%A0&inputs=lol&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>40</s> 33 bytes

```powershell
$l=$args.Count
!($args|?{+$_%$l})
```

7 bytes saved thanks to *mazzy*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9XyXHViWxKL1Yzzm/NK@ES1EDzKuxr9ZWiVdVyanV/F/LxaVSomCroOQB1JmvxKWmkqbgUAIVy8nPQRNxzk9JTc/PSUMTdkTj5@UXpKIJWSgoWMCE/gMA)

Comment: nice. you can save some bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9XyXHViWxKL1Yzzm/NK@ES1EDzKuxr9ZWiVdVyanV/F/LxaVSomCroOQB1JmvxKWmkqbgUAIVy8nPQRNxzk9JTc/PSUMTdkTj5@UXpKIJWSgoWMCE/gMA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
LḍOP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4Y5e/4D////n5OcAAA) or [Verify all cases!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4Y5e/wCuw@2PmtZkPWrc/v//fyUPoFS@ko6CUk5@Dohyzk9JTc/PSQOxHUFEXn5BKoi2UFCwUAIA)

**Commmented:** <sup>(At least I think it works like this)</sup>

```python
   P  # product of ...
L     #   does the length 
 ḍ    #   ... divide ...
  O   #   the char codes
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
⍱≢|⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1Hvxkedi2oe9U0NdQ7@n/aobcKj3r5HXc2Petc86t1yaL3xo7aJQMngIGcgGeLhCVSj7pGak5OvzpWmnpOfA6Kc81NS0/Nz0kBsRxCRl1@QCqItFBQs1AE)

`⍱` are not any of the following true (non-zero)?

`≢` the length

`|` divides (lit. division remainder when dividing)

`⎕UCS` the code points

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 25 bytes

```cs
a=>a.All(x=>x%a.Length<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBa8MwDIXP8a8QhUECa2DnNIFSGD10MLbDDmMHzVFdg2Jttjs6Sn975iSs9LBB30GgxyfpIR3mWjz1@2CdgefvEKmr1GVXbqz7rJRSDjsKH6gJVtKSEd6qo4IkzRgCPHoxHrvRmfxBIWK0Gr7EtvCA1uUh@rT79Q3Qm1CcuaPKMoD7vdOLibiFdxFuYJssqHusGyyXzPmhbg43WG7Imbhb3BV9ipZl2UpcEKbyxdtIKTHlw2A@WxOzzIqiOl8a9B/Nwlezv0@4emA5kn@iT4TtSF6sOqmpnvof)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

*Edit: -1byte thanks to the new rule that we can output TRUE for FALSE and FALSE for TRUE*

```r
function(s)any(utf8ToInt(s)%%nchar(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfk5qXXpIRn5JZlpmSWhyfk1pSklpUbPs/rTQvuSQzP0@jWDMxr1KjtCTNIiTfM68EyFdVzUvOSCwCsjRxaNdQ8kjNyclX0uTCJZ@Tn4NH1jk/JTU9PycNjxJHPHJ5@QWpeKQtFBQs8EiHBkQ5BgDl/wMA)

Or try the [original 39-byte version](https://tio.run/##fcsxDoMwDAXQvaegSEjJDbJ0QF1gYyhLF4SIA5Esu0oM109zAbx9/fd/Kgi0y7H4eEUPeUEQgZRfJZy0SWQy2a6I5nlKcB8eSWrRdbQda6rJ3vxNOwAit/Zx58io6Js97IxBmfSKEf9AYdc0TuF5@vZT9fIH) that outputs TRUE for TRUE...

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-e`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
c vNÎÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWU&code=YyB2Ts7K&input=IkhlbGxvIg)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
$h÷╓
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18l4/D2R1Mn//8freShpKOUCsQ5UJyvFMsVDWWBREA8ZygvBao2HS6ro5QGVuEIJvOg4gVgdSARCyBLAYotlGIB)

**Explanation:**

```python
$     # Get the codepoint of each character in the (implicit) input-list
 h    # Push the length of this list (without popping the list itself)
  ÷   # Check for each codepoint if it's divisible by this length
   ╓  # Pop and push the minimum of the list
      # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
!$+(A_Ma)%#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fUUVbwzHeN1FTVTnx////efkFqQA)

### Explanation

```
!$+(A_Ma)%#a a → input
   (A_Ma)    Map a to Unicode/ASCII codepoints
         %#a Modulo the list by it's length
 $+          Sum up the remainders
!            Not(returns 0 for any positive number, 1 for 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```python
N=input();print(not sum([ord(i)%len(N) for i in N]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoBQCADQq7gEOjdGV/AC0VaRYCrmHzq9vRdf3W5zN69iMQppiRQrNC94x4Ob54FCk56GTHB5goAY8E7Ura4/)

Comment: I think your `map` would be shorter as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})((r||=#c%$#1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCsIwEAbg/X@Kg8ZyN3YtOIiLryExZ4TDk6QO1fjsKcXxg@9Tc1cW7uqFInH4cp1nmX7CXFo7DvEQhkmkC7CXSoxLMnOc/ZbuboqnvxJOMDe4KvRRIFAKlcaRUsxOerW6Umt/LeW95LVv)

If we accept a "list of characters" as arguments, then we don't have to split the string for **19 bytes**:

```sh
for c;((r||=#c%$#))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCsJADAXQ/T9FoLUkV6i4EDdeQ8aJIwQjk7poHc8@Ii7f26J0ZeGuXintmWtrhyHtxkGkC/DrIMY5mzlOfs03N8XDnxlHmBtcFXqvECiNb455lvjQNFFOxUkvFiu19tdSX0tZ@xc)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 20 bytes

```
.,0@{(3$%@+\}3$*;!\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0/HwKFaw1hF1UE7ptZYRctaMcb6//@c/BwA)

This outputs 1 if the string is divisible and 0 if it isn't.
Let S be the string and L its length.

```
.,0@                  # The stack from bottom up will be: L  0  S
    {       }3$*      # Execute this block L times
     (                # Separate first char from the string as a number
      3$%             # Previous number mod L
         @+\          # Add result to the acumulator
                ;     # Discard the ""
                 !    # 1 iff the acumulator is 0
                  \;  # Discard L
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
¬⊙θ﹪℅ιＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMvv0TDMa9So1BHwTc/pTQnX8O/KCUzLzFHI1NTR8EnNS@9JEOjUBMErP//t1BQsOD6r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for true, nothing for false. Explanation:

```
  θ         Input string
 ⊙          Is there a character where
     ι      Current character
    ℅       Ordinal
   ﹪        Modulo (i.e. is not divisible by)
       θ    Input string
      Ｌ     Length
¬           Boolean NOT
            Implicitly print
```

`⬤θ¬﹪℅ιＬθ` also works of course.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 62 bytes

```
: f ( s -- ? ) dup length [ mod ] curry [ + ] map-reduce 0 = ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9asMwFIX3PsXBU0ux6WhsSggptF68lEwlgyJfOaKypF5JAVP67M4lHc7v8Bmlc@Dt@DmM7x0Us1oTvok9OSwqX@7WmOJ1tsEnJPop5DUlRKac18jWZ/QPw9jhzV5tsmdHdcpyz2nrYPCIhLrGDk@YSoQjPwv2C0uYcIIuzKusZ@mLijXTVDThBa/ot19UH@RcqFC54MQPYaI5OCN1L/IhkkQLtBX@hGL@KWi2Gw)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 81 bytes

```cs
(s)=>{var bs = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);return bs.All(b=>b%s.Length==0);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY47C8IwFIX3/opQEFLQ4B5TaOur0M3BuYmXGgg3kpsWRPztNbSj4zl852FoZ8jO2XlEc6AYLA5bVnvvoMeSrUZLRztZstoBU2zmVKjyM/WBaUq6ujVte0LjHwkVixIXiPU7AiVUBohjwMSKyjmuVak3JDrAIT6V2hfyK@d1hll8jTE15ldwzucyazxSeiLuwUboLAL/O8SXUFHI@Qc)

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <strike>27</strike> 26 bytes

```cs
s=>s.All(c=>c%s.Length<1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczLCsIwEIXhfZ9iKAgpaMB1m4AXRKF71zoMdWCYSCf19WOwS7eH/3xoOzQuzWVRHCzPrNMWjikJPTTCOtzszB82fgpBgGIhmj@IOAwRN@ZH0im/hn3Xl7UH1veSa9peSSS1fXNKapX095kzjazk/mT3O3UV@QI)

Comment: You can use `s.Length<1` instead of `s.Length==0` like in my answer

Comment: Thanks @LiefdeWen , I hadn't thought of that until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 21 bytes

```
&L
|%o 1
€l|!
rM@dp
```

#### Explanation

We `r`ead a string and `€`xplode it, push the stack `l`ength and `M`emorize that.

Then, after setting the exception catch point (`@`), we always `d`uplicate the top stack element, negate (`!`) it, and m`|`rror horizontally if we get a truthy value (string has ended; we popped a 0). Otherwise,  we get the `o`rdinal of the character, `L`oad the memorized value and do modulo (`%`). If this is truthy, we m`|`rror again.

Finally, we raise an exception (`&`) to land back in front of the `d`, for our next character.

If we mirrored, then we eventually land on `p`, printing the top-most element of the stack. In one of the two cases of mirroring, we will have pushed a `1` before.

---

I don't see much potential to golf this down further; there's only one space character used, and 3 newlines. Perhaps one or two bytes could be saved by making it a 16x16 in two lines.

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
`|_=M0=A0/[M%{0:.}?`]1:
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%60%7C_%3DM0%3DA0%2F%5BM%25%7B0%3A.%7D%3F%60%5D1%3A&input=8%20%208)

Thanks to @Razetime for saving 9 bytes!

Explanation:

```
`        Remove starting 1 on stack
|        Push input on stack as ASCII codes
_=M      Set variable M to length of stack (length of input)
0=A      Set variable A to 0
0/       Push 0 and cycle stack
[        Start of loop
M%       Modulo by M
{0:.}    If not 0 then print 0 and terminate
?`       If 0 then pop value
]        End of loop
1:       Print 1
```

Comment: why not add the condition in the first loop itself?

Comment: [Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%60%7C_%3DM0%3DA0%2F%5BM%25%7B0%3A.%7D%3C%60%3E%5D1%3A&input=8%20%208) (I think the link generator needs to point to MAWP 2.0.)

Comment: @Razetime yep, fixed link gen, thanks

Comment: Small edit(again): change the `<%>` conditional to `?%` or its equivalent in 2.0

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 41 chars

```
(every? #(= 0 (mod (int %) (count x))) x)
```

Removing spaces after comment **37 chars**

```
(every? #(= 0(mod(int %)(count x)))x)
```

Comment: are some of the spaces not removable?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a code-golf challenge, so the aim is to minimise your code as much as possible. As Razetime mentioned, is it possible to remove some/all of the spaces in your code? Also, make sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Clojure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/tips-for-golfing-in-clojure) page

Comment: Oh, good point. I thought the Clojure compiler would moan without the spaces.

Comment: You can generate Stack Exchange markdown answers from your working code at https://tio.run/#clojure . It's the general place we use to check each other's answers around here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ạfᵐ∋ᵛ~l?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSuVv2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f7hrYRqQftTR/XDr7Loc@///o5U8UnNy8pV0FJRy8nNAlHN@Smp6fk4aiO0IIvLyC1JBtIWCgoVS7H8A)

```
ạfᵐ∋ᵛ~l?
ạ        characters to integer
 fᵐ      find all factors
   ∋ᵛ    every list of factors contain …
     ~l? the length of the input
```

Alternative version,

```
⟨ạzl⟩%ᵛ0
⟨fhg⟩    forks! fA & gB ∧ [A, B]h
 ạzl     zip the code blocks with the length;
          [[108, 3], [111, 3], [108, 3]]
     %ᵛ0 every list must be 0 after modulo
```

Answer (score 1):

## NARS2000 (12 characters)

`(∧/0=⍴|⎕ucs)`

Fork `⍴|⎕ucs` finds residue of each ASCII int value when divided by length of string. `∧/0=` checks if all residue are zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>63</s> 49 bytes

```python
lambda h:print({0}=={*[ord(i)%len(h)for i in h]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfbBvzPycxNyklUSHDqqAoM69Eo9qg1ta2Wis6vyhFI1NTNSc1TyNDMy2/SCFTITNPISO2VvN/sYZSTn6OkiYXkJFUVJoBYVkoKFgoaf4HAA)

`*` in the `{}` constructs a `set` which I think is more byte-efficient than using `set()`, [which I didn't know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47313267/12581541).

----

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 42? bytes

```python
lambda h:{0}=={*[ord(i)%len(h)for i in h]}
```

I can't get TIO to output the `True` or `False`. This works with IDLE or Jupyter. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfbBvzPycxNyklUSHDqtqg1ta2Wis6vyhFI1NTNSc1TyNDMy2/SCFTITNPISO29n@xhlJOfo6S5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 30 bytes

```powershell
!(($args|?{(++$l)})|?{+$_%$l})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Pa8JAEMXv@ymmsNZdYu6CFCNe9FRpjqWENJlEZcym@wcLcT97ujEWyZx23u@9x2yrrqjNEYniQmnseQVv0PUvQvBc1@a27kQUcZJehmfEsxknL3vPWCLYQsx3IajmC@BVTgblIJGiQbDajftWlVgrqqauzcTTqBanfAmwfFok3GAGHYMw3Fh9aurA8LfFwmIZLubZyDQaRzYIr@Ejyei8k89DunXGqsv79zmEvpIOUlcUaMyQfsRi/Hm2ruDjv@zBV7BvWncXxmbwzPd/)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 41 bytes

```
s->s.chars().allMatch(i->i%s.length()==0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcyxasQwDAbgPU8hDgr2ENPx4JpA6dLloHBj6aA6TuJUsYOlHJRyz566XMnsfxGSPv4Jr1hP3dfm5yUmgSnvZhVPpl@DFR@DeUuu8xbFnapl/SRvwRIywxl9gJ8Kcv7vLCh5XKPvYM5fdZHkw/D@AZgG1nf7l73y6S5a6JuN65aNHTGx0gaJzih2VL5u/QMbcmGQUemmedTbaS@6fLO42cRVzJKLhILqjTgWdXh1RPGgdRGmSKX0JXZuiNSX@udSGOLiSu0R4LjbW3XbfgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
Λo¦L¹c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zs/EPLfA7tTP7//39Ofg4A)

#### Explanation

```
Λo¦L¹c   translates = Λo¦L⁰c⁰
Λ     ⁰  all of input:
 o   c   charcode
  ¦      divides
   L⁰    length of input
```

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 23 bytes

`!(x(ƒ(i %(↶(∋) l(⋒)))))`

Explanation:

```
!(           Not
  x(         Any list item is true
    ƒ(       List-builder for
      i      Input
      %(     Modulo
        ↶(   ASCII codepoint
          ∋  Loop item
       )
       l(    Length of
         ⋒   Loop iterator (what the loop is looping through)
       )
     )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
lḊp
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWwlRTElQjglOEFwJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9bG9sJmZsYWdzPUI=)

##### Explanation

```python
lḊp  # Implicit input
     # Convert to charcodes
l    # Length of input
 Ḋ   # Are they divisible
  p  # Product of the list
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `K`, 3 bytes

```
LḊΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=L%E1%B8%8A%CE%A0&inputs=lole&header=&footer=)

I too can play the K flag game, especially given that I invented it.

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 38 characters

```
length as$a|explode|map(.%$a)|all(.<1)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ jq -R 'length as$a|explode|map(.%$a)|all(.<1)' <<< 'Hello'
false

bash-5.2$ jq -R 'length as$a|explode|map(.%$a)|all(.<1)' <<< 'lol'
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8nNS@9JEMhsVglsSa1oiAnPyW1JjexQENPVSVRsyYxJ0dDz8ZQE6guP@dffkFJZn5e8X9d3aLEct3MvILSEgA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lZA9b4MwEIZn/CuuiMQwEJpMkQpSo6pSO1XKCqhy4QhpXZtiI0UK@e3UBqkpQ4cu9@Xn7t7zG1P1UGLBWYsQ7kCj0q8FU5j4xEnpE3IuaZ7QinGF1Ja45Lag227KH2SJB8mrObWbMUI2OH/fAmyvSEBI0x6FroD2sAg3twqsX8/9xthMUKDPoum08XtUHbfB46nBQmNpwpcPSkglWzhayFhwvfPNz1npfX5x76CUxGnH7sT1fHj/gnAPdOAoDroGpjzW46nh5rT@kzX@auGxoGec@6t4HQwU4jg2c8cVLgQuIc4/9BtBY2cUedTkUZaJi2uqkyAbna96pyX5CPiQpr@4JPkLzXNYLgGLWo4fYhWWUuDwDQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](https://clang.llvm.org), <s>149</s> 148 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){char s[100];scanf("%s",s);int j;int k=strlen(s);for(int i=0;i<k;i++){if(s[i]%k>0){printf("0");return 0;}};printf("1");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczBCoMwEATQe79CLEKCbYnnVX9EPIRo6tZ0Ldl4Cn57Ggu9zOHNMOZunKZnSlck4/ZpbjlMuD2W/oIUirdGEjKaRfuCh0apEdhosqKsuLyxhHP0@uXacfBuJpHVbl6chp0CbFfAupYRreABx2rtlYwfn/t8o0oJfg67p0LBccDfm@xHSm5zXw)

Comment: I think you can leave out the ```#include <stdio.h>``` and it will still run fine (just giving a few more warnings)...

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P1Mnyzo3MTNPI1uzOjkjsUihONrQwCDWOi2/SCPLtig1MUXDQKdYByimaZ1pk2Wtma1mWxydqa0dq5plY2hdUFoC0qVhYqGdrWld@/9/Tn4OAA "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 66 bytes

```
=SUM(MOD(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1))/LEN(A1),1))=0
```

Input is in the cell `A1`.

`ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1)))` gives us an array of values from 1 to the length of the input.
`MID(A1,ROW(~),1)` pulls out each character of the input, one at a time.
`CODE(MID(~)` converts those characters to their decimal ASCII equivalent.
`MOD(CODE(~)/LEN(A1),1)` returns just the decimal portion of those codes divided by the input length.
`SUM(MOD(~))=0` adds up all those decimal portions and returns `TRUE` if there weren't any (SUM=0 means everything divided nicely) and `FALSE` if there were.

---

I thought this would have to be an array formula but it seems to work without that. Color me surprised.

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 65 bytes

Returns 1 for true, 0 for false

```sql
SELECT-1/~max(ascii(substring(@,number,1))%len(@))FROM spt_values
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1293088/divisible-strings)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 76 bytes

```go
func f(a string)int{for _,v:=range a{if int(v)%len(a)>0{return 0}}
return 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCsMgEADP9RVLoOBCD@ZasF8pS1Ar3a7BmlzEt1tDe@ltGIYJqa@0PCk4eFGU7jdZwGuCd8lRAkYp1acM98t@tZlkdFSjh@H1jmd2oglvpmZXtixgWlM/nNt3dmw1QlWndRwLi/Z64sQTWjvjn3045nR4g6r1PqIP)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, 10 bytes

```
00000000: 880e 0601 acd4 0ae1 fbc3                 ..........
```

Listing:

```
88 0E 0106      MOV  BYTE PTR[CHR_LOOP+2], CL   ; move len to second byte of AAM opcode 
            CHR_LOOP: 
AC              LODSB                           ; AL = next char 
D4 0A           AAM  CL                         ; ZF = (AL % CL == 0) 
E1 FB           LOOPZ CHR_LOOP                  ; loop if CX > 0 AND ZF = 1 
C3              RET                             ; return to caller
```

As a callable function. Input: string in `SI`, length in `CX`.  Output: `ZF` = `1` if `Truthy`, `ZF` = `0` if `Falsey`.

Output of DOS test program:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 33 bytes

```
[ dup length '[ _ mod 0 = ] ∀ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xCsIwFEX3fsWli1txkqI4iIO6uIhTKRLS1xp8fYlJOtTJ0e/0R2JwuOee5XJ7paP16Xo5nQ9rPMgLMQI9JxJNAb2fMap4/6OaxGjbEZynGGfnjUQMJOQVm5eKxkrApijKIzHbsijZcuY@TwbLfdZdjlhHuWqgLlODbnJgkiF/LBrcMNoOS2zR4vt5o00riHKOZ1QBmkn59AM)